# Windows batch Script to select week number when calling a file

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have considered to incorporate a batch file in my SSIS package to put a file into an SFTP site via winscp.com and therefore need to write a batch file at the end which can put the needed file into a SFTP site, for which I have written the process below but I need help to call the file which looks like Filename_Week #(eg. Filename_1,file name_2...Filename_34) and is located M:\Test\DATA OUT folder. My feeling is to add an if statement (i.e. if [%v_week%] == [] SET v_week= week #) after set v_week=%1, but I am not sure what that would be since I have never written a batch file before.

```
SET v_week=%1
echo option batch continue > SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
echo option confirm off >> SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
echo open target >> SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
echo lcd "M:\Test\DATA OUT" >> SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
echo cd / >> SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
echo put "M:\Test\DATA OUT\Filename_%v_week%.txt" /Filename_%v_week%.txt >> SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
echo exit >> SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
M:\temp\apps\WinSCP\winscp.com/script="M:\Development\SFTPBatchFiles\SFTP_Filename_Put.txt"
del SFTP_Filename_Put.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to get the week number automatically ?

Comment: ... based on current date?

Comment: I need the batch file to look for the filename_week#.FYI I have variable called v_week in my SSIS package. This package is run every Thursday and today I happen to run week 35; where the week 35 start_dt =03/23/2014 and end_dt=03/29/2014 and Package_processed_dt=20140403

Comment: Your code do that already: `echo put "M:\Test\DATA OUT\Filename_%v_week%.txt"`. Excuse me, but you distract us with unnecessary details and don't focus on the point. Please, clearly explain what is your problem: what you have now and what you want to have; don't include details unrelated to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Like this it will automatically get the last created `.fyi` file and get the last 2 chars
and set your `V_week` variable.

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.fyi) do set $WeekNb=%%~na
set $WeekNb=%$WeekNb:~-2%

set v_week=%$WeekNB%

echo The Week Number Is : %v_week%

pause
```

Comment: hello sachadee, Could help me understand as to how I could combine your script with that of mine. Cause I tried to do it and it would return v_week as -2. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Is my code working alone ? Are you getting the Week number ? I Put a `pause` at the end that you can test.